# Should I use multiple AMQP queues on a microservices architecture?

Tags: architecture, redux, microservices, amqp

Wondering about a microservices architecture using AMQP as messaging protocol, I begin to see a similarity with the redux front-end architecture.

With that said, my actual question is:

Is there some limitation on using a single AMQP queue for all the services deployed? Or is there some benefit of having multiple queues?

Comment: One benefit to having a cluster of AMQP queues (where everything is mirrored) is high availability - your system can tolerate an AMQP node going down, without turning down clients. An obvious disadvantage is the increased complexity of setting up your queue(s). Whether it's a benefit to you, depends on whether this level of availability is strictly important to your system. For instance you might tolerate your system being down while the AMQP node is restarted.

Comment: A reasonable point! Thank you!

Comment: Apropos, you should make your microservice's core (the Domain layer in DDD) to be agnostic of the way the messages arrive at it. All it should know is how a message is processed, not how it arrived there.